# Where to add new chaincode for Fabric in Chaincode Dev mode

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to run / update chaincode in the Chaincode-docker-dev mode from the **Fabric samples release v1.1**

I am able run,invoke,query chaincode_example02.go as per the README . 
Now i want to add a new chaincode or update/upgrade exiting chaincode .

Where should i add the new chaincode ,how ? tell me the steps please

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it . Had to put the chaincode in the 'chaincode' folder in Fabric-release-samples 1.1 and then go build it , add it to the existing peer ,,execute accordingly .